# What is the relationship between the size of the data saved by the smart contract and the size of the actual computer storage resource consumption?

Tags: contract-development, storage, blockchain-size

I want to know, for example, I am passing 1KB of data to the function in the smart contract, and save the 1KB data in the smart contract through the storage variable. I want to know how much storage resources of my local computer are actually consumed after I use the smart contract to store 1KB of data? What is the relationship between the size of the data saved by the smart contract and the size of the actual computer storage resource consumption? The method I currently think of is to store 1KB multiple times, and then calculate the change in the size of the local Geth folder.

Hope you can help me!Thanks!